# How to open a html page as a popup with in the page (no new window opens) using Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having the link button and when i clicked on the link button the popup will be open (with in the page itself like a modalpopup. now i have to get the popup feel using jquery and inside the div text should come from database.
How is it possible for getting the message from the backend.

means open a div in a modal popup feel using jquery

or opens the html page in a popup in the same window using jquery

Thanks and Regards
Vara Prasad.M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) jQuery plugin.  It does pretty much exactly what you're asking for.  For example you can have a link like this to some remote page like so

```
<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

then just call the facebox plugin when your content is loaded like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
});
```

and your content will render in a modal window.  You can also take a look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) which provide very similar functionality.

Comment: Thanq very much i got the answer

Answer (score -1):

There are two steps to your problem:

1. Open a modal popup using jQuery
2. Fetch server side content and display it in the modal dialog

Use jQuery Dialog (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) for popping open a modal dialog, and then use jQuery load (http://api.jquery.com/load/) for loading the content from the server.

The server page you call will make the database query and output the contents to the response buffer.